# Fresco animated preloader

Tags: android, animation, fresco

How can I set gif from res:/ to SimpleDraweeView as preloader for another uri? Facebook says, if I want to use animated images in SDV, I must use a controller, BUT, I must use a controller to download image from url as well, and I cant use two controllers at same time.
PS. 
placeholder cant show animated images,
view.setLowResImageRequest() dont show animation

```
        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setUri(uriLocalGIF)
                .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
               .build();
        view.setController(controller);
```

This one will show animation. So what am I supposed to do with image in web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animated images are not currently supported for the low-res request, unfortunately. You can file an issue on GitHub to consider adding this capability to Fresco.